# Script Task gives error 'One or more errors occurred.'

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, script-task

Whenever I try to create a Script Task in SSIS, it gives me the following error:

> One or more errors occurred.

Even though I haven't done any changes in the script task and added no line of code. I use a Visual Studio 2019 community version. This error persists for any script task I create and is not limited to the current project. I tried updating Visual Studio and SQL Server Integration Services components, but it changed nothing.

This problem has been bugging me for quite some time now, as I'm unable to proceed with my learning due to this. The screenshot is attached for reference.

[image: Screenshot of error in Script task with no code changes done.]

Comment: Try to double click on the error message it should navigate to the error cause.

Comment: @Hadi I tried. I get a message box with the error message 'Failed to navigate to the source'.

Comment: One suggestion: check if the `TargetServerVersion` is accurate: https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project

Comment: What are the specific version numbers of Visual Studio 2019 and the [SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) you have installed? Not every version is compatible with every other version since Microsoft tends to only test new extension releases against the latest version of VS2019.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Please find the details of my installed software. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.5. SQL Server Data tools 16.0.62107.28140. SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.2000.180

Comment: @Hadi I tried changing the `TargetServerVersion` to every avaialble SQL Server version I had avaialble. It did not solve the issue. I'm still unable to build an empty script task. It gives the same error as before.